# cast null value from database

Tags: integer, row, sql-null

I have a form that takes data from a database, I want to convert the data from null to a value of 0 in case there is no row in the database, I tried a lot but did not find the solution

```
{
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select max(Inv_no) from Tb_agentSales";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds.Fill(dt);
                   
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 )
        {
            double result = (Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) +1);
            textBox23.Text = result.ToString();
        }
     

        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select max(Inv_no) from Tb_agentSales";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds.Fill(dt);

    double result;         
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && cmd.ExecuteScalar() is {} d)
    {
        result = (Convert.ToDouble(d) + 1);
        textBox23.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    else {
        result = 0;
    }
    

    con.Close();

}
```

This should work, be aware that I haven't tested it though.

Comment: yes its working , but if the database Null , will return error because its can't caste to int or double

Comment: @المدارللانترنت I edited it, to accommodate that. Hope that it helps :)